# Center image (vertically) in Navigation List

Tags: html, css, image, navigation, center

I am trying to create a navigation list that is responsive and also have the image centered inside the list on the page

I have managed to get close to that however, the image is higher up than the list.

Im trying to get it like this but can't seem to figure it out. 
[image]
Any help would be appreciated!

**CODE: https://jsfiddle.net/z50zgpLg/**

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <header>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>Portfolio</li>
                    <li id="logo">
                        <img src="images/sonis.png"/>
                    </li>
                    </li>
                    <li>About</li>
                    <li>Contact</li>
                </ul>
            </header>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
                margin:0px;
                padding:0px;
            }
            .container-fluid {
                border: 1px solid red;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .nav {
                border: 1px solid black;
                width: 60%; 
                margin:0 auto;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .nav li {
                display: inline-block;
                border: 1px solid red;
            }

            #logo {
                height: auto;
                width: 100px;
            }

            #logo img {
                width: 100px;
                height: auto;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `vertical-align:middle`

**CSS**

```
 .nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/z50zgpLg/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align:middle` to the `li` CSS. The default for inline-block items is `baseline` and you have to change that.

```
.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a working fiddle here emulating what you are looking for. https://jsfiddle.net/41hgusjr/

I simply added `padding-bottom: 5px;` and `padding-top:5px;` to both logo, and the img.

of course, this makes the nav a big larger.